# Creating a linq query which results in only 1 query execution

Tags: linq

I have the following two tables:
*tableA 
*tableB

TableA has a 1 to many relationship with tableB and therefore TableB has a column with a foreign key for tableA

TableA will be used to create a c# class called classA which has a bool property indicating wether it has related records in TableB called HasRecords

I could create it like this:

```
TableA.Select(s => new ClassA {
      Hasrecords = s.TableB.Any()
}
```

Will this create 1 query or multiple ones because of the any function? Is there another way to do this in line without triggering multiple query executions or do I have to resort to a table valued function?

Comment: It depends of the query provider (ORM) used. If you have in mind EF6, yes, it will translate to single SQL query.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev: yes I mean EF6. The reason I am asking is because I am getting a bit confused on the immediate execution now. Does Any() not cause immediate execution?

Comment: When used inside `IQueryable<T>` expression tree - no. You can easily check that by using something like `var sql = db.TableA.Select(...).ToString()` and examining the `sql` variable in the VS Locals or Watch window.

Comment: Or get a copy of LINQPad and see the SQL translation for queries.